# How to get full date value from HTML using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, parsing

I am trying to get date from HTML using selenium. The problem is, that in the HTML (if viewed through the console in a browser) I see the full date like 01.01.2001, but selenium returns me 01.January what I should do, to get full date?

The part of HTML(what I see in the browser console) looks like this:

```
<div>
   <h4 class="status-param"> Name and Surname </h4>
   <h4 class="status-param"> Date of Birth: 01.01.2001 </h4>     <!--problem only with this -->
   <h4 class="status-param"> 12.12.2012 00:00 </h4>
</div>
```

my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chrome/chromedriver')
        driver.get(html)
        result = []
        try:
            elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "status-param"))
            )

            for element in elements:
                result.append(element.text)
        finally:
            driver.quit()
```

I get the following

```
'Name and Surname'
'Date of Birth:  01.January'
'12.12.2012'
```

Comment: use python inbuilt date module and convert string date to dateobject

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't convert it, because I get only day and month, without year. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below xpath  :

```
(//div/h4[@class='status-param'])[2]
```

and use it like this :

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div/h4[@class='status-param'])[2]"))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(elements)
```

the above should only prints `01.01.2001`

**Update 1 :**

You can simply break string into 2 parts ang grab the second part like this :

```
print(elements.split("\\:")[1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help, Sorry, I forgot to write that in this "h4" I have not only a date, but also a text. It completely looks like this: Date of Birth: 01.01.2001
p.s. Thanks! I have already add this in my question.

Comment: when you used the above xpath, what was the output ?

Comment: @Kung you can use regular expressions to separate the date, or use str split function so that you can only get date part of the text

Comment: @cruisepandey and Santhosh Reddy Thanks for the help, it turned out that while I was writing the code and parsing the page, the owners of that site changed the values and now transmit them in the format: 01. January. So cruisepandey, your code turned out to be working.